# Delete two first words and first words in a string (title wordpress)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, algorithm

currently I use tags in my wordpress article titles and place them at the beginning.

https://alerte-prolo.fr/les-alertes-alimentaires/
https://alerte-prolo.fr/alimentaire/acheter-ses-fruits-et-legumes-moins-chers/

I want to keep the tags in the category pages, but in the articles (single.php) I want to delete the tags.

currently I use this to lift the first word of the title.

```
<h2>
    $originalTitle = the_title('','',false);
    echo substr($originalTitle,strpos($originalTitle, ' '));
</h2>
```

t works with [Astuce], [gratuit] ect
but when I have tag [bon plan] it would be necessary to be able to delete the first two words.
I need help for this. 
thanks

Comment: i have edit my first link

Comment: You shouldn't post links to external websites without posting the content here (what if the site goes down for some reason?). Please post your samples here alongside their expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this working for you:

```
<?php
$originalTitle = "[bon plan] Some Title"; //  In your case: $originalTitle = the_title('','',false);
$newTitle = explode( "] " , $originalTitle, 2);
echo $newTitle[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly:

```
$originalTitle = "[wtf] [this one to] Some Title";
$newOriginalTitle = preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$originalTitle);
echo $newOriginalTitle;
```

`/\[` - defining start

`\]` - defining end

Comment: @kwiz it can't work with `the_title();` because this function echo it already, but you can use `get_the_title();` instead.